# What is the difference between mov dword ptr [eax], 5 and mov dword [eax], 5?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, intel-syntax

What is the difference between the operations:

```
mov dword ptr [eax], 5
```

and

```
mov dword [eax], 5
```

Furthermore, do

```
mov dword ptr [eax], 5
```

and

```
mov [eax], dword ptr 5
```

do the same thing?

Comment: Nothing, they are for different assemblers. Note that a particular assembler may accept the other syntax too and do something unexpected. `masm` uses `dword ptr` for accessing a 4 byte unit of memory but `dword [eax]` I believe gets assembled as `4[eax]` meaning `[4+eax]`.

Comment: In assemblers supporting the `dword ptr` form, the `mov [eax], dword ptr 5` is (or should be) illegal.

Comment: What about 

mov dword [eax], 5

vs

mov [eax], dword  5

Comment: E.g. in `nasm` those are both allowed and equivalent. You should really specify which assembler you are using.

Comment: I am using nasm.

Comment: I believe newer versions of `nasm` support more `masm` like features. But historically, `nasm` did not support `dword ptr`.

Comment: I see. Thank You. 
I also have another question though. If I were to write `mov [eax+10], 20`, would that be equivalent to `mov [eax+10h], 20` or `mov [eax+10d], 20` (in nasm, obviously)?

Comment: Numbers are in decimal unless otherwise stated. See [numeric constants in the manual](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.1).

Comment: @Jester: NASM 2.15.05 (latest stable) rejects `mov dword ptr [eax], 5`, but it has a special warning to remind you that it's not NASM syntax: `warning: 'ptr' is not a NASM keyword [-w+ptr]`.  Then `error: symbol 'ptr' not defined`.  If you want it to assemble, you'd need to `%define ptr` (to nothing)